# How to add arrays of objects when deserializing with SwiftyJSON

Tags: arrays, swift, swifty-json

I am working on deserializing JSON with SwiftyJSON and Swift 5.1.

I have a set of data like below

```
"name": "American Standard",
            "number": 1,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "American Light Lager",
                    "letter": "A",
                    "guidelines": {
                        "overallImpression": "Some String",
                        "aroma": "Some String",
                        "appearance": "Some String",
                        "flavor": "Some String",
                        "mouthfeel": "Some String",
                        "comments": "Some String",
                        "history": "Some String",
                        "ingredients": "Some String",
                        "comparison": "Some String",
                        "vitalStatistics": {
                            "og": "1.028 - 1.040",
                            "fg": "0.998 - 1.008",
                            "abv": "2.8 - 4.2%",
                            "ibu": "8 - 12",
                            "srm": "2 - 3"
                        }
                   },
                   "commercialExamples": [
                       {
                            "name": "name1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "name2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "name3"
                        },
                    ],
                    "tags": [
                        {
                            "tag": "tag1"
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": "tag2"
                        },
                    ]
                },
```

I am using struct to hold all the data, shown below.

```
struct Beers
{
    var name: String
    var number: Int
    var subcategories: Subcategory
}

struct Subcategory
{
    var name: String
    var letter: String
    var guidelines: Guidelines
    var commercialExamples: [CommercialExample]
    var tags: [Tag]
}

struct Guidelines
{
    var overallImpression: String
    var aroma: String
    var appearance: String
    var flavor: String
    var mouthfeel: String
    var comments: String
    var history: String
    var ingredients: String
    var comparison: String
    var vitalStatistics: VitalStatistics
}

struct VitalStatistics
{
    var og: String
    var fg: String
    var abv: String
    var ibu: String
    var srm: String
}

struct CommercialExample : Hashable
{
    var name: String
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)
    {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
}

struct Tag : Hashable
{
    var tag: String
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)
    {
        hasher.combine(tag)
    }
}
```

And for my deserialization code, I have this.

```
for (index, dict) in jsonObject
{
    let thisBeer = Beers(name: dict["name"].stringValue, number: dict["number"].intValue, subcategories: Subcategory(name: dict["name"].stringValue, letter: dict["letter"].stringValue, guidelines: Guidelines(overallImpression: dict["overallImpression"].stringValue, aroma: dict["aroma"].stringValue, appearance: dict["appearance"].stringValue, flavor: dict["flavor"].stringValue, mouthfeel: dict["mouthfeel"].stringValue, comments: dict["comments"].stringValue, history: dict["history"].stringValue, ingredients: dict["ingredients"].stringValue, comparison: dict["comparison"].stringValue, vitalStatistics: VitalStatistics(og: dict["og"].stringValue, fg: dict["fg"].stringValue, abv: dict["abv"].stringValue, ibu: dict["ibu"].stringValue, srm: dict["srm"].stringValue)), commercialExamples: CommercialExample(name: dict["name"].stringValue), tags: Tag(tags: dict["tags"].stringValue)))
    beers.append(thisBeer)
}
```

This is where I am stuck.  I am much more familiar with C# and .net. I just don't know how to go about looping through the commercialExamples and tags and creating the objects from the data and populating the arrays with them. What is the proper way of doing this with Swift and SwiftyJSON?

Comment: Forget `SwiftyJSON` in favor of `Codable`. It parses the JSON into the structs without any additional code.

Answer (score 0):

You must first use JSONSerializable protocols to decode your JSON data into the object. For example in your case:

```
struct Beers: JSONSerializable {
var name: String?
var number: Int?
var subcategories: Subcategory?

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case name
      case number
      case subcategories
   }
}

extension Beers: Decodable {
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    if let value = try values.decodeIfPresent(String?.self, forKey: .name) {
        if let value = value {
            name = value
        }
    }
    if let value = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int?.self, forKey: .number) {
        if let value = value {
            number = value
        }
    }
    if let value = try values.decodeIfPresent(Subcategory?.self, forKey: .subcategories) {
        if let value = value {
            subcategories = value
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Then you can make an object from JSON data like this:

```
do {
        let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(Beers.self, from: jsonData)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
```